# Cannot repeat ng-content in *ngFor

Tags: angular, ngfor, ng-content

I have a seemingly very simple problem in Angular. I am using Angular 14.1.

I am passing some content to be projected from a parent component, `IssueCredentialsComponent`, whose template looks like this:

```
<hr-portal-passport-list-view [passports]="(passports$ | async) ?? []" [allPassportsCount]="passportCount$ | async">
  <span title>Issue credentials to passports</span>
  <span description>Confirm identity and issue credentials to passports.</span>
  <a href="#" action>Issue credentials</a>
</hr-portal-passport-list-view>
```

...and in my child component, `PassportListView (hr-portal-pasport-list-view)`, I am using `*ngFor` to create table rows for each passport.

Now, the action link is rendered by `ng-content` within the `*ngFor`. Like this:

```
<tr *ngFor="let passport of passports">
   <!-- -->
   <ng-content select="[action]"></ng-content>
   <!-- -->
</tr>
```

For reasons I can appreciate, the content is only rendered once, at the end of the array; whereas I need it to render for every row. This content is static (for the moment) and so there doesn't need to be any logic or anything of that sort.

I understand the problem, but not the solution! I have variously tried creating a template, rendering the content in there and referencing it within the `*ngFor` using `ng-container`. Using `@ContentChild()` and a few other bits and pieces. None of this works.

Help?

Comment: Can you create stackblitz?

Comment: Hmm, not really. NDAs and stuff.

Comment: No need to share all code just create some reproducible example

Comment: Worked it out! See below.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I put on my big boy pants and managed to work it out.

I changed my parent to look like this:

```
<hr-portal-passport-list-view [passports]="(passports$ | async) ?? []" [allPassportsCount]="passportCount$ | async">
  <span title>Issue credentials to passports</span>
  <span description>Confirm identity and issue credentials to passports.</span>
  <ng-template #action>Issue credentials</ng-template>
</hr-portal-passport-list-view>
```

and updated the child component to include:

```
@ContentChild('action', { static: false }) actionTemplateRef: TemplateRef<any> | null = null;
```

and in the template:

```
<ng-container [ngTemplateOutlet]="actionTemplateRef"></ng-container>
```